# Fetching only selective fields using ElasticSearch RestHighLevelClient

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using RestHighLevelClient to fetch documents from ES storage.

```
.....
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(60L));
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.size(100);
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("id", id));
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("my-index");
searchRequest.scroll(scroll);
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Currently this fetches all fields, but I want to fetch only a specific field.

How can this be done using RestHighLevelClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html#_source_filtering) and pass the array of field names that you want to fetch, below request added on according to your example will fetch only `title` fields and exclude everything else in response.

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(60L));
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.size(100);
String[] includeFields = new String[] {"title"};
sourceBuilder.fetchSource(includeFields, null);
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("id", id));
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("my-index");
searchRequest.scroll(scroll);
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```